# How to change all characters in every cell of an R dataframe

Tags: r, string, dataframe, dictionary, character

Say i got an R dataframe A like so:

```
  a   b
1 nbc dkf
2 lei ao
```

How do I get a new dataframe B:

```
  a   b
1 gfr ais 
2 ykl db
```

If I have two vectors that contain the starting characters and the ending characters like so:

```
start = c(a,b,c,d,e,f,l,k,i,n,o)
end =   c(d,f,r,a,k,s,y,i,l,g,b)
```

Comment: are those variable or letters in the vectors and you forgot the 'a' around it?

Comment: Looks similar to encryption/decryption approaches like found in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60332706/substitution-encryption-decryption-in-r).

Comment: @peter they are the names of the columns

Comment: Ah, seems I misunderstood your question

Comment: @ben yes it is similar and the solution below involves chartr too, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
start <- paste(start, collapse="")
end <- paste(end, collapse="")

dfB <- df
dfB[] <- lapply(dfB, chartr, old = start, new = end)
dfB

    a   b
1 gfr asi
2 ykl  db
```

Reproducible data (please provide yourself next time):

```
df <- data.frame(
  a = c("nbc", "lei"),
  b = c("dfk", "ao")
)
start = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "l", "k", "i", "n", "o")
end =   c("d", "f", "r", "a", "k", "s", "y", "i", "l", "g", "b")
```